# Skipping over tags and spaces in regex html

Tags: javascript, html, regex, tags

I'm using this regex to find a String that starts with !?, ends with ?!, and has another variable inbetween (in this example "a891d050"). This is what I use:

```
var pattern = new RegExp(/!\\?.*\s*(a891d050){1}.*\s*\\?!/);
```

It matches correctly agains this one:

```
!?v8qbQ5LZDnFLsny7VmVe09HJFL1/WfGD2A:::a891d050?!
```

But fails when the string is broken up with html tags.

```
<span class="userContent"><span>!?v8qbQ5LZDnFLsny7VmVe09HJFL1/</span><wbr /><span class="word_break"></span>WfGD2A:::a891d050?!</span></div></div></div></div>
```

I tried adding **\s** and ***{space}****, but it still fails. 
The question is, what (special?)characters do I need to account for if I want to ignore whitespace and html tags in my match.
**edit:** this is how I use the regex:

```
var pattern = /!\?[\s\S]*a891d050[\s\S]*\?!/;

document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML.replace(pattern,"new content");
```

It appears to me that when it encounters the 'plain' string it replaces is correctly. But when faced with String with classes around it and inside, it makes a mess of the classes **or** doesn't replace at all depending on the context. So I decided to try [jquery-replacetext-plugin](http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-replacetext-plugin/)*(as it promises to leave tags as they were)* like this:

```
$("body *").replaceText( pattern, "new content" );
```

But with no success, the results are the same as before.

Comment: `new RegExp(/.../)` is wrong. It should be either `/.../` or `new RegExp("...")`. Also, `{1}` is 100% redundant.

Comment: And, FWIW,  the sequence `.*\s*` can be just `.*` since you are not capturing anything.

Comment: Shouldn't each `\\?` in your regex be `\?` instead? `\\?` optionally matches an actual backslash character, whereas `\?` matches a question mark. Also, having `{1}` is redundant, that would happen by default.

Comment: [It does match](http://jsfiddle.net/K2n8L/) on your html string (at least, it worked in Chrome).

Comment: @nnnnnn Could you explain how you tested it? It doesn't work here with Chrome. Chrome is the only browser I need too.

Comment: My previous comment contains a link to the successful test - which also worked in the Miren browser on my phone. Maybe you should update your question to show how you're using the regex...

Comment: @nnnnnn didn't see it, sorry; updated.

Comment: @user1064536 I think your real issue is not the regex itself, but the fact that the replace breaks the html in the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was *apparently* solved by using this regex:

```
var pattern = /(!\?)(?:<(?:"[^"]*"['"]*|'[^']*'['"]*|[^'">])*?>)?(.)*?(a891d050)(?:<(?:"[^"]*"['"]*|'[^']*'['"]*|[^'">])*?>)?(.)*?(\?!)/;
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this:

```
var pattern = /!\?[\s\S]*a891d050[\s\S]*\?!/;
```

[\s\S] should match any character. I have also removed {1}.